# How to form Regex for XML closing tags

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex expression which will add one node in my xml.

My current xml is:

```
<A>
<B>some value</b>
</A>
```

My expected xml is:

```
<A>
<B>some value</b>
<C>some new value</C>
</A>
```

So i want to add the C element.

Can anyone help me to write the regex, i am quite new in writing regex.

Thanks

Comment: [Use a XML parser instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1225328)

Comment: You can't really use regex for that. Regular expressions are used for pattern matching.

Comment: Sorry but i can't use xml parser. I need to update this in my entire xml which is quite huge. And to write a new parser i need to update many things and a deployment process. Whereas with Regex nothing needs to be changed.

Comment: Come again: you want to write a new parser to process 'your XML'?

Comment: NO I dont want a xml parser. I want REGEX expression

Comment: I actually meant that you don't need to write a parser to process your own flavor of XML (as long as it's a flavor, not a new language).

Answer (score 0):

If you're after something quick and hacky, something like this should work:

```
s/\(<B>.*<\/b>\)/\1<C>Some new value<\/c>/
```

Comment: How about `.*?` instead of `.*` and also turn off case sensitivity?